# Display different pages in same page view web part

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

I have a normal sharepoint page, on it I have a page viewer web part that views a page, what I want to be able to do is create 2 links on the page, when each link is displayed it shows a different page in the same page viewer.  I am pretty new to code so any assistance greatly recieved

Answer (score 1):

The pageviewer webpart is basically an iframe. So what I would do is create a JavaScript/jQuery function that triggers on click of your links. The script should update the iframe src.

Look here for a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730159/4699406